# Review my jQuery plugin structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I'm trying to learn learning javascript and jQuery plugin standards, and after some googling and testing I've come up with this pattern:

```
;(function(window, document, $, undefined){
  var plugin = function(element){
    var instance = this,
        somePrivateFunc = function(){
          console.log(instance.options);
        };

    this.options = $(element).data();
    this.publicFunc = function(){     
     somePrivateFunc();
    };
  }

  $.fn.myplugin = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
      if(!$(this).data('_myplugin')){
        var myplugin = new plugin(this);
        myplugin.publicFunc();
        $(this).data('_myplugin', myplugin);
      }
    });     
  }

}(window, document, jQuery));
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/4NAXb/

Is this OK? Do you have any suggestions on improving it? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/).

Comment: What is the leading `;` for?

Comment: idk.. i've just seen ppl do it :s

Comment: @svick It's explaned on the boilerplate: *The semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Use `$.data(this, '_myplugin')` & `$.data(this, '_myplugin', myplugin)`. They're SO MUCH faster.
2. Since you call `.publicFunc` every time you instantiate your plugin, you should probably move the call into your constructor instead.
3. Public functions should be assigned to the prototype, so that we don't create a new function every time we create a new instance.
4. Likewise, define a private function outside of the constructor, in the parent closure. Again, we don't want to have to re-create the same function over and over again.

```js
;(function ( window, document, $ ) {

  function somePrivateFunc ( instance ) {
    console.log( instance.options );
  }

  var Plugin = function( element ) {
    // What is this?
    this.options = $(element).data();
    this.publicFunc();
  }

  Plugin.prototype.publicFunc = function () {     
   somePrivateFunc( this );
  };

  $.fn.myplugin = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
      if ( ! $.data(this, '_myplugin') ) {
        $.data( this, '_myplugin', new Plugin(this) );
      }
    });     
  };

}(window, document, jQuery));
```

**P.S.** You haven't described how you're exposing the plugin's additional methods. For that you should read the [jQuery plugin creation tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/).

Find the section titled **Provide Public Access to Secondary Functions as Applicable**.